# Java Reflection get only methods of subclass (without equals, hashcode etc)

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to get the methods of an Class object, without getting the methods defined by the Object class?

Right now I am using getDeclaredMethods() to look for a specific method with a list of parameters.

My problem is that this also returns functions like
"equals", "hashCode", etc...
and thus it could be ambiguous between these functions and the one I'm looking for.

Looking at the documentation, it says that it only returns the public methods defined by this class (or in my case an interface), and my objects never override these methods

Is there any workaround for this?

Example:

```
class Test implements ITest {
   void myMethod() {...}
}
```

and in my code I have something like

```
Object o = new Test();
for (Method m : o.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) { 
    System.out.println(m.getName()...);
}
```

and this prints me methods defined in the Object class

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] .

Comment: class Test implements ITest {
    void myMethod() {...}
}

and in my code I have something like

Object o = new Test();

for (Method m : o.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
    System.out.println(m.getName()...);
}




and this prints me methods defined in the Object class

Comment: I'm sure your `Test` class implements them. Othweriwse provide an example which shows what you discover. Maybe the methods comming from some bytecode instrumentation (e.g. Lombok).

Comment: Don't post code examples in comments. As you see there is no proper code formatting for comments which makes it hard to read. Also you shouldn't make people willing to help you search for important information all around this post. Put all important info in question itself. Use [edit] option for that.

Comment: If you do a simple test with for example the java.nio.file.Paths class, you can see that the method getDeclaredMethods() only returns the methods declared in the Paths class. The method getMethods() also returns the inherited methods. So it looks like your class overrides them indeed.

Comment: for your question you could do a set difference operation, that is, you class methods minus `Object` methods, but as it was pointed by the ones before me it seems that your test class overrides some `Object` methods indeed

Comment: If `getDeclaredMethods` is returning inherited methods that are not re-declared, it would imply a bug in the JVM. As that is a highly unlikely scenario, I'd suggest you double-check your code and observations.

Answer (score 2):

`getMethods()`returns all methods declared by a class, plus methods declared in the object class. You can use `getDeclaredMethods()` to access methods that are class specific or implemented from super class. Example:

```
  interface IChild {
     int child1(int a, int b);
  }
    static class ChildImpl implements IChild {
        @Override
        public int child1(int a, int b) {
            return a*b;
        }
        public int child2(int x, int y){
            return  x+x*y;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IChild i=new ChildImpl();
        System.out.println("===Non Object Methods===");
        for(Method m:i.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()){
            System.out.println("Declared Method"+m.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("===All Methods===");
        for(Method m:i.getClass().getMethods()){
            System.out.println("Method: "+m.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

===Non Object Methods===

Declared Method: child2

Declared Method: child1

===All Methods===
Method: child2

Method: child1

Method: wait

Method: wait

Method: wait

Method: equals

Method: toString

Method: hashCode

Method: getClass

Method: notify

Method: notifyAll